# Add a custom application tab to user's pages

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am initially asking a

> manage_pages

permission whenever a user is authorizing my app. I would now like to add a custom tab i.e. the user can change the name of the tab which gets added to his facebook page. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook recently added the ability to programmatically (via the Graph API) create and modify tabs. Take a look at the tabs section of the Page docs:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#tabs

Answer (score 5):

Thanks Mirko... I checked the documentation and found that we can use graph api to make tabs as

```
$facebook->api("/PAGE_ID/tabs","post", array("access_token" => $accessToken,  "app_id" => $appId));
```

though i was actually passing the 'user access token' in the above code instead of 'page access token as suggested by Lix in the other reply.

Fonally i found out that the page access token can be obtained by

```
$pageIds=$facebook->api('/me/accounts');
$pageAccessToken=$pageIds["data"][1]["access_token"];
$facebook->api("/PAGE_ID/tabs","post", array("access_token" => $pageAccessToken,  "app_id" => $appId));
```

Comment: hey this works great !! how can i give different name to tab at the time of adding page.

Comment: try to pass the `name` field in the array with other POST data
`"name"=>"My Custom Name"`
check out [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/tabs/](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/tabs/)

Answer (score 0):

if you goto the page settings ( top right corner of page - "edit page" button), and then navigate to the "apps" tab - you can change the name of the tab that was added by clicking on "edit settings" next to its name.

Comment: I actually wanted to do it through some php code. I am currently able to get all the pages of a user by using the graph api and "/me/accounts" but i am not being able to call the url "www.facebook.com/add.php?api_key=".$appId."&page=".$pageIds" through "file_get_contents".

Comment: ohh ok - well what you'll have to do is make a call to `PAGE_ID/tabs` with a **page** access token.

From the facebook docs :

`You can install a profile_tab at the end of the current list of installed tabs for a page by issuing an HTTP POST request to PAGE_ID/tabs with a Page Access Token` [facebook pages](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#tabs)